# About structs - c

Tags: c, struct, scanf

So I am trying to write this piece of code and test a few things out with structs.. It compiles but when I reach the "scanf("%d",sp[i].cylinder);" exe crashes when I give scanf an int input..Am I missing something obvious here?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct car {
    char name[20];      
    char company[20]; 
    int  cylinder;  
    int  year;
    int  plates;        
};

struct car *sp;   

void function();

int main() {
    int maxcars=3;
    printf("Give number of cars \n");
    //scanf("%d", &maxcars);

    function(maxcars);

    printf("There are %d cars\n", maxcars);

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < maxcars; i++){
        printf("%s\n", i, sp[i].name);
        printf("%s\n", i, sp[i].company);
        printf("%d\n", i, sp[i].cylinder);
        printf("%d\n", i, sp[i].year);
        printf("%d\n", i, sp[i].plates);
    }

    if (sp) {
        free(sp);
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void function(int maxcars) {
    // 


    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < maxcars; i++) {
        sp = malloc(maxcars * sizeof(struct car));
        printf("Struct for car no%d is beeing created\n", i);
        printf("Give Name: \n");
        scanf("%s",sp[i].name);
        printf("Give Manufactorer Company: \n");
        scanf("%s",sp[i].company);
        printf("Give Cylinder Capacity: \n");
        scanf("%d",sp[i].cylinder);
        printf("Give Year of Production: \n");
        scanf("%d",sp[i].year);
        printf("Give Plate Number: \n");
        scanf("%d",sp[i].plates);

        printf("%s\n",sp[i].name);
        printf("%s\n",sp[i].company);
        printf("%d\n",sp[i].cylinder);
        printf("%d\n",sp[i].year);
        printf("%d\n",sp[i].plates);
    }
}
```

//edit : fixed some later for after the function where i had a couple typos but wouldn't affect my main issue..crashing still happening

//edit 2- solution: It was eventually the & missing in scanf..thanks for pointing it out dave!i had a feeling it was something obvious..

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Windows has stopped working and it's checking for a solution for that error with that loading bar...bad memory allocation?

Comment: looks like you should call malloc outside the for loop in function()